# Reset old cookies before loading $_COOKIES

Tags: php, cookies, coldfusion, firewall, mod-security

I'm moving an old web-application written in **ColdFusion** to **PHP5**.
The old app was using a cookie, and so a lot of user got it in their browsers.

The domain is the same and so PHP5 gets the old cookie in the auto-global `$_COOKIE`, in other words the resulting `print_r( $_COOKIE )` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [CFID] => 10753812
    [CFTOKEN] => 81032420
    [CFGLOBALS] => urltoken=CFID#=10753812&CFTOKEN#=81032420#lastvisit={ts \'2011-12-07 11:51:43\'}#timecreated={ts \'2011-11-28 01:19:23\'}#hitcount=3#cftoken=81032420#cfid=10753812#
)
```

That's overall ok, except for the application firewall **ModSecurity2**: autoloading $_COOKIES the firewall detect it as evil. Before with a false positive SQL injection, then with some XSS attacks matches.

I can disable those rules, but isn't the best solution (I think).

How can I check if the ColdFusion cookie exists?
How can I remove old cookie from user's browser without autloloading it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a specific **ModSecurity2** rule and a PHP bridge page:

1) HTTP layer: when cookie is present, redirect to...
In Apache's config:

```
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES:CFGLOBALS !^$ "phase:1,nolog,pass,redirect:http://www.abcde.com/cookie_reset.php"
```

2) Application layer: so reset old cookies.
In the page cookie_reset.php

```
<?php

setcookie ("CFID", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("CFTOKEN", "", time() - 3600);
setcookie ("CFGLOBALS", "", time() - 3600);

header("Location: http://www.abcde.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try (php 5.3?) this php ini conf:

```
auto_globals_jit = On
```

then, setcookie(....) to reset, after this, access $_COOKIE to read

Comment: That's unapplicable, just-in-time loading affects only $_SERVER and $_ENV.

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution can be use javascript in a bridge page

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.cookie="";</script>
```